# restrict first-child to only the first child and no descendants

Tags: html, css

In the following snippet, I only want the first `div` after the legend which has the text `one` and nothing else but is selecting `three` also

```css
.container fieldset div:first-of-type {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
      <legen>blah</legen>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two
          <div>three</div>
        </div>
        <div>three</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you only want the "three" div and you have to use an `nth/first-` selector? There are no other options?

Comment: You **do** or **don't** want the first div?

Comment: ...or you only what the `one` div?

Comment: @dagda1 I didn't try to close your question I made it clearer. Move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you only want to select the div with "one" and not the div with "three" who is inside div "two", right?

Then use the direct descendant selector `>`

```css
.container fieldset > div:first-of-type {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
      <legen>blah</legen>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two
          <div>three</div>
        </div>
        <div>three</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

```css
.container fieldset div:first-of-type {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
      <legen>blah</legen>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two
          <div>three</div>
        </div>
        <div>three</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```